# Profiling http request with OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

How to track detailed request time with OkHttp.

I want to get:

- connection time;
- sending time;
- receiving time;

I tried to use Interceptors mechanism, but it provides only total request time.

```
class LoggingInterceptor implements Interceptor {
  @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();

    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    logger.info(String.format("Sending request %s on %s%n%s",
        request.url(), chain.connection(), request.headers()));

    Response response = chain.proceed(request);

    long t2 = System.nanoTime();
    logger.info(String.format("Received response for %s in %.1fms%n%s",
        response.request().url(), (t2 - t1) / 1e6d, response.headers()));

    return response;
  }
}

// sample request
String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {

  MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
  client.networkInterceptors().add(new LoggingInterceptor());

  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an implementation of a logging interceptor provided by Square [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.java). It does log the total request time. It also will log the `Ok-Http-Sent` and `Ok-Http-Received` headers. I do not know enough of the implementation details to know what those mean, and the documentation is sparse.

I also recommend Facebook's [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) library. It provides a reasonably detailed view of requests. In particular, it will track "latency" and "time" (neither of which line up with the metrics provided by OkHttp logging). Their [implementation](https://github.com/facebook/stetho/blob/master/stetho-okhttp3/src/main/java/com/facebook/stetho/okhttp3/StethoInterceptor.java) of the interceptor may also help you derive your own logging mechanism.

There is a pending [stetho issue](https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/312) that discusses adding more detailed information, similar to executing a query in the browser (profiling dns lookup, ssl handshaking, etc), however it looks like it requires (significant?) modifications to OkHttp before being viable.

Answer (score 3):

Use `response.receivedResponseAtMillis()` And `response.sentRequestAtMillis()` instead

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use OkHttp Profiler plugin to debug requests directly in the Android studio

[image: plugin screenshot]

https://github.com/itkacher/OkHttpProfiler

2. You can use Charles proxy application

More details about the Charles setup https://link.medium.com/KU8QBMMRjR