# How to get HTTP request/response timings in android

Tags: android, okhttp

I need to log these:

1. DNS time
2. Connection time
3. SSL time
4. Device network Bandwidth
5. First byte time
6. Transfer time
7. No of objects/No of bytes

I am using OKHttp library for network requests.

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34909440/5110595)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at OkHttp's new EventListener: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Events

It provides a way to hook-up listener to every step of the chain, so you can get info like so:

```
class PrintingEventListener extends EventListener {
  private long callStartNanos;

  private void printEvent(String name) {
    long nowNanos = System.nanoTime();
    if (name.equals("callStart")) {
      callStartNanos = nowNanos;
    }
    long elapsedNanos = nowNanos - callStartNanos;
    System.out.printf("%.3f %s%n", elapsedNanos / 1000000000d, name);
  }

  @Override public void callStart(Call call) {
    printEvent("callStart");
  }

  @Override public void callEnd(Call call) {
    printEvent("callEnd");
  }

  @Override public void dnsStart(Call call, String domainName) {
    printEvent("dnsStart");
  }

  @Override public void dnsEnd(Call call, String domainName, List<InetAddress> inetAddressList) {
    printEvent("dnsEnd");
  }

  ...
}
```

And you hook it up like this:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("https://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt")
    .build();

System.out.println("REQUEST 1 (new connection)");
try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
  // Consume and discard the response body.
  response.body().source().readByteString();
}
```

Which will output the following:

```
REQUEST 1 (new connection)
0.000 callStart
0.010 dnsStart
0.017 dnsEnd
0.025 connectStart
0.117 secureConnectStart
0.586 secureConnectEnd
0.586 connectEnd
0.587 connectionAcquired
0.588 requestHeadersStart
0.590 requestHeadersEnd
0.591 responseHeadersStart
0.675 responseHeadersEnd
0.676 responseBodyStart
0.679 responseBodyEnd
0.679 connectionReleased
0.680 callEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

Add HttpLoggingInterceptor.It logs the total request time. It also will log the Ok-Http-Sent and Ok-Http-Received headers.

```
public static Retrofit getInstance() {
if (instance == null) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();          
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();           
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);  // <-- this is the important line!
    instance = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Constant.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();
}
return instance;
}
```

And add the following dependency:

```
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

AS you have mention you are using OKHttp library for HTTP calling, OKHttp library provide facility to print logs of every single API call that you need using logging-interceptor dependency.

You can have more details in below link and follow the steps of below link.
https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/06/retrofit-okhttp-logging-interceptor.html